# TypeScript - Class Members Missing From New Object Instance

Tags: typescript

I suspect what I'm about to describe is the expected behavior, except I didn't expect it, it seems a bad choice, and I can't find any documentation describing it.

I created a simple Typescript class for use in an Angular app as part of a Provider.  I mention the last part just in case it's relevant, but I don't think it is.

Here's the class

```
class Config {
    public settings: Object;
    public locale: Object;

    public $get: () => Config;

    constructor() {
        this.$get = () => this;
    }
}
```

I have tried various and sundry versions of the above code (using "any" instead of Object, different takes on defining $get, etc.) but the only versions which produce an object that has both member variables (settings/locale) are versions where I explicitly set a value to them.  For example, the code below will produce an object with a settings member (set to the empty object {}), but no locale member:

```
class Config {
    public settings: Object;
    public locale: Object;

    public $get: () => Config;

    constructor() {
        this.settings = {};
        this.$get = () => this;
    }
}
```

What I would expect, in general, is for uninitialized typed member variables to be present, having the default value for their type ("any", I suppose, would reasonably be undefined) so, in this case, settings would still be {}, but so would locale.

This is definitely not happening and I'm just looking for someone to confirm that what I'm seeing is the correct behavior and (hopefully) point me to the documentation or otherwise explain why this is.

I don't doubt there's a good reason, it just escapes me as to what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Some people think that class instances should initialize all their members. Some people think that they should only initialize explicitly-initialized members. Which should the compiler do?

It's easy to understand how to "opt-in" to initialization:

```
class Config {
    public settings: Object = undefined;
    /* ... */
}
```

If you imagine the reverse design where the member is automatically initialized, it's very unclear how you would indicate to the compiler that you *don't* want `settings` to be initialized.